# Facing issue while reading graphs using chromevox

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I am using ChromeVox for accessibility testing in my project. I am facing an issue while trying to provide aria tags for graphs. I read that we can use aria-describedby to describe graphs. But ChromeVox does not read the description while navigating forward from one control to the graph. It reads the description while navigating backward.
I have isolated the issue in a simple application. In my example, I have a heading “Index”, then for the graph I have used a rectangle. And then I have a button “Click”.

Image: Sample web application for reading graph description using ChromeVox:

[image]

In the above web page when I focus on “Index” heading and then navigate forward to “graphDiv” div, ChromeVox just reads the aria-label “graph” and does not read the description from the “mydesc” div. If I navigate backward from the "Click" button to “graphDiv” div, ChromeVox reads the description.

Code Snippet:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<div id=”outerDiv”>
    <div id="mydesc" style="display:none"> This is a red rectangle </div>   
    <div id=”graphDiv” tabindex="0" aria-label="graph" aria-describedby="mydesc" >
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 80, 80);
        </script>
    </div>
    <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

I edited the code by removing the “outerDiv”. Now ChromeVox has the intended behavior, i.e. it reads the description when moving from "Index" to “graphDiv” div and also from "Click" button to “graphDiv” div.

Edited code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="mydesc" style="display:none"> This is a red rectangle </div>  
    <div tabindex="0" aria-label="graph" aria-describedby="mydesc" >
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 80, 80);
        </script>
    </div>
    <button>Click</button>
```